# /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:87: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.5) or chardet (5.2.0) doesn't match a supported

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm having problems. I believe are caused by `selenium`, as every thing was working fine until I imported it into my project..

The error im getting is:

```
]:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:87: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.5) or chardet (5.2.0) doesn't match a supported version!
]:warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "

OS = ubuntu server
```

It's not running in a virtual environment.

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, can anyone shed some light on the issue.

Attempted to import selenium in a python file.

I tried installing both `chardet` and `urllib3`, through pip and apt yet neither seem to work.

I have also attempted to update requests, `chardet` and `urllib3` that doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

- either upgrade requests library and chardet to the version from your OS distribution (see what's available with **apt show python-requests** and **apt show python-chardet**), or
- install latest version of requests and chardet in virtualenv (preferred)